# How do I add form-level validation to a Flatland Form class?

Tags: python, forms

I have a [flatland](http://discorporate.us/projects/flatland/) form for a proxy website that looks something like this:

```
class doSomethingForm(Form):
  '''Do an action with account credentials'''
  username = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), UsernameFormat()])
  password = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), PasswordFormat()])
  action = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), ActionFormat()])
```

If any of the parameters are empty, I want the validation error to be that the given elements are empty.  If they are non-empty and meet other requirements, then the next step is to ask the other service if the credentials are valid.  If they are invalid, then I want to turn that into a validation error.

This looks a lot like flatland's container-level validation, which runs validation on the contained elements first.  So I tried this:

```
class doSomethingForm(Form):
  '''Do an action with account credentials'''
  account = Dict.of(
    username = String.named('username').using(default='',
      validators=[Present(), UsernameFormat()])
    password = String.named('password').using(default='',
      validators=[Present(), PasswordFormat()])
  ).using(validators=[CheckCredentials()])
  action = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), ActionFormat()])
```

This looks like it would work, but now the form is looking for elements named `account_username` and `account_password`, which isn't quite the interface I was hoping for.

I see a couple of solutions:

1. I could attach the `CheckCredentials` validator to `doSomethingForm`.  But, I don't see a way to do this in the documentation.
2. I could attach the `CheckCredentials` validator to `username`, which can [access its sibling `password`](http://discorporate.us/projects/flatland/docs/tip/validation/index.html#examining-other-elements).  However, I don't want to bother the other server if the username and password are in a bad format. so I'd have to run the validations on `username` and `password` first, which seems like repeating myself.
3. I could hack  a verson of `Dict` that doesn't do namespacing

Is there right way to add form-level validators in flatland?

Comment: Also, I'd tag this 'flatland', but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: I've added the tags for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to checkout the flatland code (`hg clone http://bitbucket.org/jek/flatland`), because the documentation and examples aren't quite there yet.

`Form` inherits from `Dict`, which inherits from `Container`, which inherits from `Element`.  There are two class elements that will help:

- `descent_validators` (from `Container`) - an iterable of Validators to run on the descent (first) phase.
- `validators` (from `Element`) - an iterable of Validators to run on the ascent (second) phase.

To get my desired behavior (check account only if the username and password are valid), I need to add my validator to the `validators` class variable, and check that the child validators passed.

My code now looks something like this:

```
class CheckCredentials(Validator):
  '''Checks credentials and creates an account object'''

  def validate(self, element, state):
    username = element['username']
    password = element['password']
    if not (username.all_valid and password.all_valid):
      return false

    self.account = Account(username.u, password.u)
    return self.account.valid()


class doSomethingForm(Form):
  '''Do an action with account credentials'''
  username = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), UsernameFormat()])
  password = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), PasswordFormat()])
  action = String.using(default='',
    validators=[Present(), ActionFormat()])

  validators = (CheckCredentials(),)

@expose('/do_something')
def doSomething(request):
  form = doSomethingForm.from_defaults()
  form.set_flat(request.form)

  result_html = ''
  method = request.method
  if method == 'POST' and not form.validate():
    method = 'GET'
    errors = []
    if form.errors: errors.extend(form.errors)
    for el in form.all_children:
      if el.errors: errors.extend(el.errors)
    result_html = errorsToHtml(errors)

  if method == 'POST':
    result_html = form.account.action(form['action'].u)

  return render_template('do_something.html',
    result=result_html, **form.value)
```

I think flatland can do some cooler things to help with generating the HTML forms, but I'm pretty happy with this so far.

Thanks to [WoLpH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54017/wolph) and [jek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106760/jek) for their help.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a bit of the docs I would assume you can simply do `your_form.validate()`.

The `Form` class inherits the `Dict` class so the way you can do validation is identical to how the container-level validation normally works.

Disclaimer: until your question I've never heard of "flatland" so I can be really off here.

Comment: Yes, this is how you validate the form (by default, `validate()` recursively validates child elements before running its own validators).  My question is how you attach a new validator at the `Form` level. The fact that `Form` inherits from `Dict` is very useful.